# Suggestions for optimization?

Tags: java, groovy

```
def antBuilder = new AntBuilder()
antBuilder.tar(basedir: getOutputDirectory(),  destfile: getTarFile())
antBuilder.gzip(src: getTarFile(), destfile: getTarGzipFile())
antBuilder.delete(file: getTarFile())
antBuilder.delete(dir: getOutputDirectory(), includes:"*.xml")
```

I have a method which does the above. As you can see the `getTarFile()` method is called thrice overall. What is the preferred way of coding it, using `getTarFile()` thrice OR defining a local variable to hold the value of `getTarFile()` and using that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get as Groovy as you want really...

You could do (for example) wrap it in a closure:

```
def doStuff = { tar, out, gzip ->
  new AntBuilder().with {
    tar( basedir: out,  destfile: tar )
    gzip( src: tar, destfile: gzip )
    delete( file: tar )
    delete( dir: out, includes:"*.xml" )
  }
}
```

And call that with:

```
doStuff( getTarFile(), getOutputDirectory(), getTarGzipFile() )
```

Whatever way you're doing it, unless getTarFile is doing loads of work (which seems unlikely), you're not going to gain much more than readability...

Though that can be a win in itself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

'Preferred' is about as subjective as you can get.

If the output of `getTarFile()` can change, then you NEED to use a local variable.

As for optimization, chances are this will get JIT compiled or otherwise optimized by the compiler. I doubt you'd notice any significant performance difference by saving the reference in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a local (bearing in mind glowcoder's caveat), because IMO it localizes the definition of the tar file above the code that uses it.

This provides a slight cognitive highlight: "Hey, there's a single tar file being referenced in the following code."

I'm optimizing for a slight conversational edge... but pretty slight. OTOH, if the tar file value needed to be manipulated, and doing so in getTarFile was undesirable, that change would be localized.

Performance-wise it's not worth thinking about, unless you have an unusually intensive file lookup. Seems unlikely ;)